# cakephp 2.3.6 login issue with the auth component

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

As far as I can tell everything as far as creating a user (person in my case) with a username and password is working fine.  When I look at the the db table the passwords are hashed and the username is saved.  the below problem occurs weather I hash the passwords or not so I think the issue is either in AppController or PeopleController

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth'=>array(
            'loginAction'=>array(
                'controller'=> 'people',
                'action'=> 'login'),
            'loginRedirect'=>array(
                'controller'=>'people', 'action'=>'index'),
            'logoutRedirect'=>array(
                'controller'=>'people', 'action'=>'index'),
            'authError'=>"You can't access that page",
            'authorize'=>array('Controller')
            )
        );

    public function isAuthorized($people)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    }
}
```

and peopleController

```
class PeopleController extends AppController
    {

        public $helpers = array('Html', 'form', 'Js');
        public $components = array('RequestHandler');


        public function beforeFilter()
        {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            $this->Auth->allow('create');
        }

        public function login()
        {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectURL());
                }
                else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect');
                }
            }
        }

        public function logout()
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }

         public function index() {


            }
```

when I try to login I keep getting the username and password do not match flash message even though I am positive I am entering the correct details, any ideas of how to trouble shoot this are appreciated

login.ctp

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php

echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');

?>
```

Comment: Turn on debug and look at the MySQL queries it's running. You should be able to see what it's trying to match in the database

Comment: Thanks, it appears to be sending the correct data with the correct field names but in sql logs it says 'warning No active database connections' so I am guessing this is the problem.  I imagine I have entered the wrong name in somewhere but if youknow where I should be looking that would behelpfull

Comment: The debugkit session info looks like this, Message>auth>message youcant access that page, element default, paramsn (empty) and Message > flash>message your username and password combination was incorrect, elemnt default, params empty.  to me that looks like it is causing the autherror function to trigger which causes the else in the peoplecontroller to trigger so it must be something going on from the model to the database that is causing the autherror to trigger?  does that sound reasonable?

Comment: please, provide source code of your login.ctp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Auth' => array(
                'loginAction' => array('controller'=>'Admin', 'action'=>'login'),
                'loginRedirect' => array('contoller'=>'Admin', 'action'=>'login'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'Admin', 'action'=>'logout'),
                'authError' => '<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                    You are not authorized to access this location</div>',
                'authenticate' => array(
                    'Form' => array(
                        'userModel' => 'User',
                        'fields' => array(
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password'=>'password')
                    )
                )
            )
```

try this.